# Every Eulerian Bipartite graph contains even number of edges.True/False

Tags: graph-theory

### Question

> Every Eulerian Bipartite graph contains even number of edges.True/False

### My Approach

> **Every Eulerian Bipartite graph.** I can extract given important points from this

- Every Vertex has even **degree**
- Number of vertex$=m+n,\text{where m and n are number of vertex in each paritite }$

Using Handshaking lemma ,

$2k*(m+n)=2*\text{Number of edges,for some constant k ,since degree of each vertex is even}$

from above too, i am unable to conclude that Eulerian Bipartite graph has even number of edges .

Where am i missing?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You're not really using that the graph is bipartite*. What does an Eulerian cycle look like in a bipartite graph?

*You're saying that each part in the bipartite graph consists of some number of vertices and that the sum of those two is equal to the total number of vertices in a graph. It might seem like you're using bipartiteness here, but the same is true even for non-bipartite graphs, as long as you partition the vertex set into two in any fashion regardless of how it respects the edges of the graph.

Comment: Obviously all the vertex will have even degree and non odd cycle

Comment: @laura You're _so close_. There are no odd cycles, that's _good_. Now couple that with the definition of an _Eulerian_ cycle, which we are told exists. What do you get?

Comment: okk , we have to have nonodd length cycle + even degree vertex , that means for any cycle of length $n$ each having even vertex , then $\frac{n \times 2k}{2}$

Comment: @laura You're focusing too much on the vertices and their degrees! (Although the other answer shows one way to do it like that as well.) I want you to just think about edges, and look at an actual Eulerian cycle, what it means that the cycle is Eulerian (not via some theorem like all vertices have even degree, but the _actual definition_ of an Eulerian cycle), and couple that with the fact that all cycles have even length. What can you conclude about the number of edges in the graph?

Comment: i think it concludes that  number of edges = number of cycle * length of cycle =even

Comment: @laura You're making this a lot more convoluted than it has to be. There is no need for any multiplications or counting the number of cycles or anything. An Eulerian cycle, by definition, contains each edge exactly once. Since it's a cycle in a bipartite graph, it must have even length. Therefore there are an even number of edges in the graph. That's the entire proof.

Comment: exactly, i made it too complex :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ and $V$ is the partition of the set of vertices in bipartite graph then $$\sum_{x\in U}\deg(x)=\sum_{x\in V}\deg(x)=k.$$ But because it is Eulerian, so $k$ is also even, say $k=2m$. So as you noticed, by handshaking lemma, $$2k=2\times|E|\Rightarrow |E|=2m.$$